# required authentication in forms

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

I have an issue with the authentication in some templates.
In template where I pass form based in models I can only access if I am logged,
but in template with forms non-based in models I can access without being logged

Form non-model based:

```
class ProvSearchForm(forms.Form):
      proveedor = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Proveedor.objects.all(),required=True)
      mes = forms.ChoiceField(
               choices = (
                          ('1',"Enero"),
                          ('2',"Febrero"),
                          ('3',"Marzo"),
                          ('4',"Abril"),
                          ('5',"Mayo"),
                          ('6',"Junio"),
                          ('7',"Julio"),
                          ('8',"Agosto"),
                          ('9',"Septiembre"),
                          ('10',"Octubre"),
                          ('11',"Noviembre"),
                          ('12',"Diciembre"),
                          ),
               widget = forms.Select()
              )
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
          super(ProvSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
          self.helper = FormHelper()
```

my view:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def BuscarView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ProvSearchForm(request.POST)
       nombre = request.POST.get('proveedor')
       mes = request.POST.get('mes')
       usuario = request.user
       if form.is_valid():
          cargaftp = Lectura_FTP()
          spftp = cargaftp.leer_ftp()
          carga = Actualizar_Descarga()
          sp = carga.actualiza(nombre,mes,usuario)
          return HttpResponseRedirect('/archivo/')
    else:
       form = ProvSearchForm()
    return render_to_response('buscarform.html',
                              {'form':form})
```

my url:

```
url(r'^buscar/$', 'pc.views.BuscarView', name='buscar'),
```

This form is take some parameters and pass it to a stored procedure, I need to pass the username from the logged user, but I get an empty (or null)  value.

In the navbar of my template I have the tag `{{ user.username }}` to render the username, but in the template where I pass the non-model based form I can't see any username and I can access without beign logged.

How can enable the authentication in the forms non-model based or how can I pass the username from the logged user to this form.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing `RequstContext` with `render_to_response`

*i.e*

```
return render_to_response('buscarform.html',
                              dict, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Thanks @Raja Simon. sorry I can upvote, but I need 15 points to upvote. I forget the context instance

Comment: @joselegit If the answer is correct then you can accept the answer by clicking the tick mark